# PHP DateTime Object Display Issue?

Tags: php, datetime

```
$currentDateTime = new DateTime();

echo "Date: " . $currentDateTime->date; // Not displaying
echo "<br>";
echo "Time: " . $currentDateTime->timezone; // Not Displaying
echo "<br>";

------------------------------------------------------------------

$currentDateTime = new DateTime();
$dataArr = (array) $currentDateTime;

echo "Date1: " . $dataArr["date"]; // Displaying
echo "<br>";
echo "Time1: " . $dataArr["timezone"]; // Displaying
```

why i am not able to access date and timezone direct from object?
i am using php 5.3.13